# Linux can-bus excessive retransmit

Tags: linux, can-bus

I'm working on a project involving a linux embedded device with CAN bus-support.

I've noticed that if I try to send a CAN-packet without having anything attached to the CAN-bus, the transmit is automatically reattempted by the kernel an unlimited number of times. I can verify this using a scope - the same message is automatically transmitted over and over. This retransmission persists even if I shut down the process which created the message, and even if this process only ever attempts to transmit one single message.

My question is - is this normal behaviour for a linux CAN bus kernel? My worry is that if there is ever something wrong in the device, and it erroneously concludes that it is alone on the bus, the device might possibly swamp the bus making it unusable for other bus participants. I would have expected there to be some sort of retry-limit.

The device is using linux 4.14.48, and the can-chip is Philips SJA1000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is likely error frames. Compliant behavior is this:

- Node is active. It attempts to send a data frame but get no ACK bits set since nobody is listening to it.
- It will send out an error frame, which pretty much only consists of 6 dominant bits to purposely break bit stuffing.
- The controller will re-attempt to send the message. If a new attempt to send without receiving ACK is done, another error frame will be sent. This will keep repeating automatically.
- After 128 errors, the node will go *error passive*, where it will still send error frames, but now with recessive level where it doesn't disrupt other traffic.
- After a total of 256 errors, the node will go *bus off* and shut up completely.

This should all be handled by the CAN controller hardware, not by the OS. You might need to reset or power cycle the SJA1000 once it goes bus off. If it never goes bus off, then something in the driver code might be continuously resetting the CAN controller after a certain amount of errors.

Mind that microcontroller implementations might act the same and reset upon errors too, since that's typically the only way to re-establish communication after a bus off. This depends on the nature of the CAN application.

Comment: Thanks for your response! There's definitely something wrong with my device then. It transmits no error frames, it just keeps blasting out the same frame over and over back-to-back without any delay, forever. If I read you correctly, this is a flagrant violation of the CAN bus spec.

Comment: @avl_sweden Yeah well... the driver _could_ be resetting the controller upon failure. But I'd still expect to see some error frames in that case. Are you sure you aren't running it in "loop back"? That is, the debug mode where the controller is told to talk with itself and ignore the actual bus?

Comment: I don't think it's in "loop back". As soon as I connect something to the bus, something which responds with 'Ack', the bus works normally. The problem only occurs when nothing is responding.

But I now noticed something. It does transmit error frames. The first 16 retransmits actually have an error frame appended after them!

Comment: According to this link: http://www.port.de/cgi-bin/CAN/CanFaqErrors , the transmit error counter should not be incremented just because an error passive node does not receive ack. Could this be why it never goes to bus off? Maybe there's nothing wrong with it then, in principle? Just a bit odd for it to have inifinite retransmits?

Comment: @avl_sweden I don't remember all the dirty details, but come to think of it, it might be correct that it will keep sending error frames forever for the no ACK error specifically. I'd have to go read up on the CAN standard to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes - if ACK is the only TEM error the counter will stop at 128 and not go into BUS OFF. It will go forever. This happened to me as well and I just turned off the re-transmit function from the processor side. Not sure if that is a CAN standard function or not.